# Did Dumbledore know that Ron would get lost?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore

Dumbledore left Ron the Deluminator, which turns out to be a way for Ron to find his friends after he runs away.

Did Dumbledore suspects such a case (so that's why he gave it to Ron)?

I remember reading something about this matter, possibly in the books.

Comment: I think he gave deluminator to Ron for this reason only ...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

1. Yes, the book said something to that effect (See @DavidS's answer for the quote) so you're remembering correctly.

   BUT, that was just Ron's personal guess and not necessarily the "truth" in-universe, so in my opinion that doesn't directly answer the question.
2. However, we do have the Word of God confirmation that he did indeed know something *in general* about Ron needing "guidance"<sup>[1]</sup>.

   > Sampotterish: Why did dumbledore want ron to keep his deluminator
   >   J.K. Rowling: Because he knew that Ron might need a little more guidance than the other two.
   >   J.K. Rowling: Dumbledore understood Ron's importance in the trio. He wasn't the most skilled, or the most intelligent, but he held them together; his humour and his good heart were essential.
   >   (*[J.K. Rowling and the Live Chat, Bloomsbury.com, July 30, 2007](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/0730-bloomsbury-chat.html) (2.00-3.00pm BST).*)

<sub>[1] ... which leads me to believe that Deluminator may have had other possible uses depending on what Ron's specific need for guidance would have been. But that's just a personal guess with no canon backup</sub>

Answer (score 21):

This is the passage in question:

> “[Dumbledore] knew what he was doing when he gave me the Deluminator, didn’t he? He – well,” Ron’s ears turned bright red and he became engrossed in a tuft of grass at his feet, which he prodded with his toe, “he must’ve known I’d run out on you.”
>
> “No,” Harry corrected him. “He must’ve always known you’d always want to come back.”
>
> — *Deathly Hallows*, chapter 20 (*Xenophilius Lovegood*)

Comment: For full transparency - this is **Ron's personal guess**, not necessarily the actual truth.

Comment: That's a good answer, but as DVK points out it's just Ron's thought

Comment: True dat, and since you've got a Word Of God quote that definitely takes precedence.